# Can different application server implementations share Remote EJBs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

After reading the official Java EE docs and after playing with OpenEJB, I am wondering about the capabilities of different application servers to cross-communicate `Remote` EJBs. Right now, it seems to me that despite the API's standardisation, the inter-process communication is not standardized, for example with the `ejbd` protocol that only seems to be supported by OpenEJB.

I am in particularly wondering about the protocols that are used for implementing EJB-based RPCs. Until now, I believed that this communication was mostly done via HTTP. From looking into the documentations for WebSphere, JBoss and TomEE, it seems however like every application server cooks its own soup.

My question is therefore: Can different application servers generally communicate via remote EJBs and by what protocol is this typically implemented. And why would an application server like TomEE offer a deriving solution in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. The EJB-Spec requires the support of CORBA/IIOP.
From the [EJB 3.1 Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) (Chapter 2.5):

> To help interoperability for EJB environments that include systems
>   from multiple vendors, the EJB specification requires compliant
>   implementations to support the interoperability protocol based on
>   CORBA/IIOP for remote invocations from Java EE clients.
>   Implementations may support other remote invocation protocols in
>   addition to IIOP.

Comment: But for example TomEE does not seem to support CORBA, is CORBA really widely supported or does this only exist on paper?

Comment: AFAIK TomEE only supports the Java EE Web Profile, which does not support remoting via CORBA (for a conparision between full and web profile see https://jaxenter.com/introducing-the-java-ee-web-profile-103275.html)

Comment: Note that interoperability is only required for EJB 3 when using java.rmi.Remote (or EJB 2.x-style EJBHome/EJBObject, which extend java.rmi.Remote).  EJB 3 "POJO"-style remote interfaces are explicitly not required to be interoperable per the spec.  Also note that there is a Java EE 8 proposal to make even this level of interoperability optional: https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/lists/jsr366-experts/archive/2015-12/message/0